# Query to display name for value instead of ID from one table

Tags: sql, primary-key

In this table is a list of individuals and some of these individuals is a parent to another individual which is specified in `parentID1` and `parentID2` columns as the `personID` value only.  I want to display the list of individuals in the first column and then the name of their parent in the second column.

[image: table data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-join the table twice:

```
select 
    t.name,
    t1.name parentName1,
    t2.name parentName2
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.personID = t.parentID1
left join mytable t2 on t2.personID = t.parentID2
```

---

Or you can use inline correlated subqueries:

```
select 
    t.name
    (select t1.name from mytable t1 where t1.personID = t.parentID1) parentName1,
    (select t1.name from mytable t2 where t2.personID = t.parentID2) parentName2
from mytable t
```

This assumes that there will not be more than 1 record in the table with a `personID` that matches a given `parentID1` or `parentID2` (else the query will fail because the inline subquery will return more than one record).

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get inner join to work and display what I wanted/needed to see so I just used a join:

SELECT c.name child, p1.name parent1, p2.name parent2
FROM dbo.person c
JOIN dbo.person p1
ON c.parentID1=p1.personID
JOIN dbo.person p2
ON c.parentID2=p2.personID

Comment: @myh: actually you need `left join`. I updated my answer shortly after posting it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I did get left join to work.  Thank you so much!  Using the same table info, if I wanted to make the query grab the parentID2 if parentID1 is null, do you know how I will achieve that and still be able to return a name value.  I am able to achieve this using (COALESCE(NULLIF(parentID1, ''), parentID2) parent) but I don't know how to use this output to get the name.

Comment: Just: `COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name)`

Comment: How will I make that return the name value then? Because the following only displays the IDs and I can't seem to figure out how I am going to pull name from the results.  I currently have this

SELECT c.name child, p1.name COALESCE(parentID1, parentID2) parent1
FROM dbo.person c
LEFT JOIN dbo.person p1
ON c.parentID1=p1.personID
LEFT JOIN dbo.person p2
ON c.parentID2=p2.personID

Comment: @myh: `COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try to use the self join feature like below query. Please try this way

```
select t.name, 

from tableName1 as t1,tableName1 as t2

where t1.personID=t2.parentID1
```